# Why Youtube's anchor tag href is redirecting instead of simply pointing to actual website address?

Tags: html, youtube, frontend, href, anchor

I'm new in the development world so excuse me if the title is confusing. I searched for a related question but I didn't find any.

So I have a question that bothers me up lately and I wanna know why youtube's  tag's href attribute is like href="https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=/*some sting here*/&q=www.somesite.com"
instead of the web site's real address like href="www.somesite.com"?

Is it for some security concerns or something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To collect data for analytics.

This is a standard technique to track clicks on the link before sending the user to a third-party site.